# Android internet Permissions

Tags: android, permissions, whitelist

When we use the internet permission in Android, it allows us to connect to the network and provided the necessary access to our websites. However, this internet permission gives access to use the entire internet. Does this make our application insecure?

Under this pretext, I'm looking for some sort of *whitelist* internet permission for Android. For instance, I would like to make a permission:

```
android.permission.Internet.google.com
```

I've been unable to find a way of implementing this.

Comment: Is what I replied [here][1] relevant?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15135540/642680

Comment: I am into research so.i would like to know the best way to make he application secure,by changing the source code or..someway or the other..ok tell me is there any other way we can have acces to internet,without using internet permission or browser

Comment: If you are talking about securing your *own* application *only* then you as the developer have full control over what access a user has but  only using your application. If you're talking about securing an android device as a whole by implementing Netfilters and iptables then you're making your phone as a whole 'secure' and that is currently a *much* more involved task on Android. Controlling access through your app is easy but remember your app CANNOT control the access of other apps this way.

Comment: Ok,I got your point,but is there any approach by which i can provide access to fetch data from particular sites only..for example either by making my permission granular in android...ie...android.permission.internet.yahoo.com or,,,can i provide access to my source code,,which can do white listing for me

Comment: You have to do the filtering in your Java source code.

Comment: Hi kery can u connect me on gmail or live.cm

Comment: my hotmail id is livinglegendary@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for users of your app to "whitelist" URL's in your application. If a user grants your app network access then your app can access the internet (all of it).

This means the user has trusted you, the developer, to not take advantage of this and use only the URL's that are safe and necessary for the app to function.

The onus is on you to ensure security. The application cannot do anything the developer hasn't programmed it to do. So you, the developer, should be conscientious and program your application to access only safe URL's. This will ensure that the user's trust in you was worthwhile and give you happy long-term customers.

Comment: I believe ,there are some crazy developers,who could create insecurity for android users????

Comment: your app will only function the way you want it to. Nobody else can change your code. So just use it safely and your app will be fine.

Comment: Only access URL's that you know are safe such as facebook,twitter or your own URL's. Don't access unknown ones. A lot of security can be ensured just by following simple principles like these.

Comment: ok,this is what i have done,but beside this is there any way a hacker could enter my appliction and steal the data.... i have read custom permission???how they are beneficial ??

Answer (score 0):

if you were trying to connect your android app to the internet, you could try to add this permition to your AndroidManifest.xml

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question. Please earn the rep required to post comments rather than posting comments as answers.